# Saving databricks pyspark df to blob storage as one file that is named and overwrites

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

As stated, we are trying to save out a pyspark df to blob storage as a single csv file. We have tried with **coalesce**. However, with the out of memory errors this can produce, we are reluctant to stick with it in a larger env.

Using `.toPandas().to_csv(f"/dbfs/filePath.csv")` produces an error that the file doesn't exist. Using `toPandas().to_csv(f"abfss://filePath.csv")` produces an error that abfss is unrecognised.

Anyone got any ways to save the csv out without the need to go down the **coalesce**, file rename, moving, and deleting route?

Thanks in advance!:)

Comment: `.toPandas().to_csv(f"/dbfs/filePath.csv")` this should work for you. can you provide a screenshot of the error? and recheck the file path and mount point.

Comment: @RakeshGovindula I had to re - mount and it went through well. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone got any ways to save the csv out without the need to go down
> the **coalesce**, file rename, moving, and deleting route?

Using the pandas can be a good option like you mentioned if you have small data. spark by default will give the extra files when writing to a file.

**Un mount the mount point and mount it again**. Sometimes, the mount point credentials may expire, and this can happen.

**Unmounting:**

```
dbutils.fs.unmount("/mnt/mountpoint")
```

[image]

**Result:**

[image]